# Symfony LeftJoin createQueryBuilder Erro

Tags: php, join, doctrine, symfony

Estou tentando executar essa query,

[image: Query com LEFT JOIN]

Minha relação não esta explicita entre Customer e Competitor;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou recebendo esse erro, que não consigo ter detalhe do que esta acontecendo,
não consigo ter o `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL()`.

[image: ERRO ao executar o $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult(1)]

essa imagem da query que fiz no bando e tento replicar no Doctrine:

[image: Query no banco de dados]

algum dica de como executar essa LeftJoin?

obrigado.

Comment: não programo mais em PHP há muitos anos e nem mesmo uso qualquer framework como symfony. Mas, uma sugestão que eu te dou, primeira coisa: Faça a query em SQL direto no banco para o que você precisa. Depois, veja se há algum recurso no Symphony que te permita mostrar o SQL gerado para testar no banco de dados e verificar se o comando funciona com os resultados esperados. Compare as duas queries. Se não funcionar você descobrirá o erro mas facilmente. 

Se você colocar isso dentro de um try-catch não consegue capturar a exceção?

Comment: @Mateus eu gerei a query desejada no banco de dados, e funciona perfeitamente. essa penúltima foto é do try catch com o erro retornado.
adicionei a foto com a query que fiz no bando de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Ajustei a o SQL:

alterei para WITH, não entendi a diferença ainda. vou pesquisar.

[image: Ajustei e funcionou]